# How many numbers are there where $x \mod 818 = 610$ and...

Tags: calculus, number-theory

How many numbers are there, where the next two conditions are met, how many such conditions are required to make it just one option for $x$?

- $x \mod 818 = 610$
- $x \mod 819 = 615$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An infinity of numbers, they are exactly the numbers of the form $n(818\cdot819)+666462$, with $n\in\mathbb Z$

The solutions to a system of conguence equations in $\mathbb Z$ are $0$ or infinite. This is because the solution will be determined $\bmod lcm(M_1,M_2\dots M_n$). Where the system is:

$x\equiv a_1\bmod M_1$

$x\equiv a_2\bmod M_2$

$\dots$

$x\equiv a_n\bmod M_n$

For more information see the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $819-818=1$ the solutions are:
$$x\equiv 610\cdot819-615\cdot818=-3480\mod 818\cdot 819\quad\text{i.e.}\quad x\equiv666\,462\mod 669\,942.$$